# Moodle get SQL data but don't get all

Tags: sql, database, moodle, moodle-api

I'm working on a plugin for showing all users completed courses.

But I only get 10 records, when I place the SQL inside my database I get 40+. I think there is a limit or it does only return 1 course from every user.

Any tips?

`externallib.php` file:

```
/**
 * External Web Service Template
 *
 * @package    specialist_in_websites
 * @copyright  2011 Moodle Pty Ltd (http://moodle.com)
 * @license    http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html GNU GPL v3 or later
 */
require_once($CFG->libdir . "/externallib.php");

class specialist_in_websites_users_courses_external extends external_api
{

    /**
     * Returns description of method parameters
     * @return external_function_parameters
     */
    public static function hello_world_parameters()
    {
        return new external_function_parameters(
                array()
        );
    }

    /**
     * Returns welcome message
     * @return string welcome message
     */
    public static function hello_world()
    {
        global $DB;

        $sql = 'SELECT u.id as user_id, c.id as course_id, DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.timecompleted),"%Y-%m-%d") AS completed_time 
        FROM mdl_course_completions AS p
        JOIN mdl_course AS c ON p.course = c.id
        JOIN mdl_user AS u ON p.userid = u.id
        WHERE c.enablecompletion = 1 ORDER BY u.id';

        $datas = $DB->get_records_sql($sql);

        return (array)$datas;
    }

    /**
     * Returns description of method result value
     * @return external_description
     */
    public static function hello_world_returns()
    {
        return new external_multiple_structure(
            new external_single_structure(
                array(
                    'user_id' => new external_value(PARAM_INT, 'user id'),
                    'course_id' => new external_value(PARAM_INT, 'course id'),
                    'completed_time' => new external_value(PARAM_TEXT, 'Time of Completed'),
                )
            )
        );
    }
}
```

and response code:

```
string(510) "[{"user_id":2,"course_id":12,"completed_time":null},{"user_id":3,"course_id":10,"completed_time":null},{"user_id":4,"course_id":9,"completed_time":null},{"user_id":5,"course_id":41,"completed_time":null},{"user_id":6,"course_id":14,"completed_time":null},{"user_id":7,"course_id":10,"completed_time":null},{"user_id":8,"course_id":9,"completed_time":null},{"user_id":9,"course_id":9,"completed_time":null},{"user_id":10,"course_id":10,"completed_time":null},{"user_id":11,"course_id":10,"completed_time":null}]"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the [docs](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Data_manipulation_API#Getting_an_hashed_array_of_records) the $DB->get_records_*() functions get a hashed array of records, indexed by the first field returned.

So, if you return more than one record with the same user_id field, then they will overwrite the previous record in the array.

Make sure you turn on [debugging](https://docs.moodle.org/en/Debugging) when developing for Moodle and you will see warning messages about this.

Solutions - either find a different field to be the first field returned (e.g. course_completions.id) or use $DB->get_recordset_sql() and then loop through the results.

Also, do not use the 'mdl_' prefix in your code, as that will break on any site with a different prefix, or if you try to run any behat or unit tests on your site. As stated in the docs, write:

```
FROM {course_completions} p
JOIN {course} c ON p.course = c.id
etc.
```

(and don't use AS with tables, as that's not compatible with all DB types)